# How to make a popup modal with an id that is a variable in the view C# mvc4

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following problem. I want to make a popup with a html form on it. I have a page with a list of movies shown in a table. And I want that if you click on a button that appears if you hover over it, it will show the modal popup.

My variable html id does change correctly depending on the movie-button you click. However, when the popup shows, it takes the first or the last movie on the page.

I understand that this is caused by the htmldocument that is loaded once. The c# list index goes over this page once and because of this I cannot call the model.Title with Javascript.

```
   @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
    {
        <tr>
            @for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                if (movieNr < Model.Count())
                {
                    if (Model.ElementAt(movieNr).ItemAfbeelding != null)
                    {
                        <td>

                            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-lg-12">

                                <div class="hovereffect">
                                    @*<p class="movie_index_item_title">@Model.ElementAt(movieNr).Titel</p>*@
                                    <img class="img-responsive" src=@Model.ElementAt(movieNr).ItemAfbeelding.Link alt=@Model.ElementAt(movieNr).Titel title="@Model.ElementAt(movieNr).Titel">
                                    <div class="overlay">


                                        <h2>@Model.ElementAt(movieNr).Titel</h2>


                                        <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
                                        <!-- The Modal -->
                                        <button class="movie_index_item_description_button" id="@movieNr">Voeg toe aan Cart</button>
```

This code above does what I want. It shows the hover effect with the buttons when I hover over it.

```
  <div id="myModal + @movieNr" class="modal">

                                            <!-- Modal content -->
                                            <div class="modal-content">
                                                <div class="modal-header + @movieNr">



                                                    <span class="close">&times;</span>
                                                    <h3>@Model.ElementAt(movieNr).Titel</h3>


                                                </div>

                                                <div class="modal-body">


                                                    <h3>hello</h3>

                                                </div>
                                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                                    <h3>Heeft u al een restaurant gereserveerd?</h3>
                                                </div>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                        <script>
                                            var modal = document.getElementById('myModal + @movieNr');
                                            var btn = document.getElementById("@movieNr");
                                            var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];




                                            btn.onclick = function () {

                                                modal.style.display = "block";

                                            }
                                            span.onclick = function () {
                                                modal.style.display = "none";
                                            }

                                            window.onclick = function (event) {
                                                if (event.target == modal) {
                                                    modal.style.display = "none";
                                                }
                                            }




                                        </script>
```

However this piece code does not work properly. It opens a modal for either the first element or last element in the list. I know this because the c# is loaded already when you hover over it. So calling ElementAt(movieNr) will show the last one.

How can I make a button that is bound by the movie you select and show a form on it for that specific movie and show the movie title on the popup.

PS: This form should go to the httppost in my controller with the filled in data.

I hope you can help us, because we are lost.

Comment: do you have to initialize the modal in JS ?

Comment: Hello mr Hussain,

Comment: I'm afraid I do not understand what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

You are not concatenating the `variable` correctly in `razor syntax` you can concatenate using `@`

```
<div id="myModal@movieNr" class="modal">
```

Comment: When I do this, my view does not recognize this as as razor c#. Furthermore this is filled correctly already when view my inspect a movie element.

Comment: @PavelTsjerenkov try with `@@` one for concatenation one for recognizing variable.

Comment: I tried this but unfortunately it does not work. Is it even possible to click on a button with variable id and get the popup for that specific element?